# how can i use wso2 behind haproxy

Tags: docker-compose, wso2-api-manager, haproxy

i use dockerized wso2 https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim.

i want use api manager behind haproxy.

my config is:

```
frontend app
  bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/wso2.pem
  default_backend wso2
backend wso2
    server node1 api-manager:9443 check ssl verify none
```

but after config it when open https://127.0.0.1/ in browser, it redirects to https://127.0.0.1:9443/publisher/.

how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the proxy ports in catalina-server.xml in repository/conf/tomcat location [1]. For 9443 port you can set the port 443 and restart the server.

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon440/Adding+a+Custom+Proxy+Path